# How to add a variable multiple times?

Tags: javascript, operators

I've been trying to make it so that you click a button, and it adds to the amount - done! Well how do you do this multiple times? As in, how do you add 1 each time? This is some of the javascript I have so far:

```
function stickAmount() {
    var y = 1;
    var stickNo = document.getElementById("stickNumber");
    stickNo.innerHTML = "Sticks: " + y;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="stickNumber" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;"></div>
```

Comment: move `y` declaration outside `stickAmount`

Comment: Because the variable is declared inside the function it will have a local scope and therefore always will be assigned the value 1 each time the function is called. You could declare `y` outside the function to make it keep it's value between function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var y=1  // move the variable outside of the function
function stickAmount()
{

var stickNo=document.getElementById("stickNumber")
stickNo.innerHTML="Sticks: "+y;
y++ // increment y by 1 every time the function is called
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yZw67/)

Comment: I was just about to post a demo :)

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a quick jsfiddle to demonstrate how it can be done.

http://jsfiddle.net/benwong/mDTFL/

HTML

```
Sticks: <span id="NumberOfSticks"></span>

<button id="AddStickButton">Add</button>
```

Javascript

```
var numberOfSticks = 1;

var numberOfSticksSpan = document.getElementById("NumberOfSticks");
numberOfSticksSpan.innerHTML = numberOfSticks;

function addStick() {
    numberOfSticks++;
    numberOfSticksSpan.innerHTML = numberOfSticks;
}

var addStickButton = document.getElementById("AddStickButton");
addStickButton.addEventListener("click", addStick, false);
```

The main thing is to define the variable for the number of sticks outside of the function which increments the number of sticks.

I moved the "Sticks: " into the HTML since you only need to change the number.

Answer (score -1):

```
function stickAmount()
{
var y=1;
var stickNo=parseInt(document.getElementById("stickNumber"));
stickNo.innerHTML="Sticks: "+y;
}


setInterval("stickAmount()",500)
```

Comment: Why `parseInt()` on `HTMLElement`?